Optimizations in branching if statements
I'm writing custom execution time formatter function for Nushell, and came across the need to display values when they are needed. First, take a look at the code:
def tooktime_fmt [exect: string] {
  let execi = ($exect | into int)
  if $execi < 1000 {
    return ([$exect, "ms"] | str join)
  } else if $execi < 60000 {
    let s_passed = ($execi / 1000 | into int)
    let ms_rem = ($execi - ($s_passed * 1000))
    return ([$s_passed, "s", $ms_rem, "ms"] | str join)
  } else if $execi < 3600000 {
    let s_passed = ($execi / 1000 | into int)
    let m_passed = ($s_passed / 60 | into int)
    let ms_rem = ($execi - ($s_passed * 1000))
    let s_rem = ($s_passed - $m_passed * 60)
    return ([$m_passed, "m", $s_rem, "s", $ms_rem, "ms"] | str join)
  } else {
    let s_passed = ($execi / 1000 | into int)
    let m_passed = ($s_passed / 60 | into int)
    let h_passed = ($s_passed / 3600 | into int)
    let ms_rem = ($execi - ($s_passed * 1000))
    let s_rem = ($s_passed - $m_passed * 60)
    let m_rem = ($m_passed - $h_passed * 60)
    return ([$h_passed, "h", $m_rem, "m", $s_rem, "s", $ms_rem, "ms"] | str join)
  }
}

It works as a charm, but, I'm concerned about memory and condition checks.
What I could have done instead:

calculate and reserve at the beginning of the function these variables: s_passed, m_passed, h_passed, ms_rem, s_rem, m_rem;
instead of branching, make a supplement function that displays the value if not 0.

For anyone wondering: I'm getting exect from $env.CMD_DURATION_MS, hence the check for errors when converting feels unnecessary.

As an aside: Instead of creating arrays and applying str join, you could use string interpolation directly, as the number of variables seems to be constant. For example: $'($s_passed) s ($ms_rem) ms'

Yes, number of variables is kind of constant, but as you can see, I'm adding leading metric every time format overflows. Nevertheless,  I should try this approach, thank you!

How about optimization your code as follow.
def tooktime_fmt(exec_time: str) -> str:
    exec_time_ms = int(exec_time)

    if exec_time_ms < 1000:
        return f"{exec_time_ms} ms"
    
    elif exec_time_ms < 60000:
        seconds = exec_time_ms // 1000
        milliseconds = exec_time_ms % 1000
        return f"{seconds}s {milliseconds}ms"
    
    elif exec_time_ms < 3600000:
        minutes = exec_time_ms // 60000
        seconds = (exec_time_ms % 60000) // 1000
        milliseconds = exec_time_ms % 1000
        return f"{minutes}m {seconds}s {milliseconds}ms"
    
    else:
        hours = exec_time_ms // 3600000
        minutes = (exec_time_ms % 3600000) // 60000
        seconds = (exec_time_ms % 60000) // 1000
        milliseconds = exec_time_ms % 1000
        return f"{hours}h {minutes}m {seconds}s {milliseconds}ms"

Please try this.
Best wishes.

Interesting, thanks  Reading through documentation and trying modulo symbol myself, I found that it % does not exist  Still, good point, I can use mod operator to perform a calculation. Wasn't too sure it will work as intended. Thann you very much ☺️

You are welcome. I pleasure my answer help you.

Turning a duration-like formatted string into a duration already gives you a broken down representation:
$'($env.CMD_DURATION_MS)ms' | into duration

7min 41sec 138ms

To access the parts individually, further turn that into a record:
$'($env.CMD_DURATION_MS)ms' | into duration | into record

╭─────────────┬─────╮
│ minute      │ 7   │
│ second      │ 41  │
│ millisecond │ 138 │
│ sign        │ +   │
╰─────────────┴─────╯


Wow, I should've read documentation more thoroughly. Maybe I will use it instead of mine. Thanks you!  Anyway, do you have any thoughts on my approach?
